# multiple divs with scrapy

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using scrapy, and the structure that i am trying to get data from is as below:

```
<div class="AA BB">
  <span data-format-supply data-format-value="16">16</span>HAYA
</div>
<div class="AA BB">
  <span data-format-supply data-format-value="21">42</span>
  <span data-format-supply data-format-value="21">21</span>HAYA
</div>
```

I want to extract the text within second div span. For example, in this case, I want to extract 21. My code is as below:

```
def parse(self, response):
sel = Selector(response)
sel.css('div.coin-summary-item-detail').extract()
```

My question is , how do I select the second AA class using css ? and after that, how do I specify that I want only the text inside second span ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you !!!

Comment: A little complicated way would be: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/842

Answer (score 0):

`.extract()` returns a list of div's matching that path. So you can iterate and print the required css class. There are methods to extract the first element but not the second ones.

Please try:

```
 def parse(self, response):
     sel = Selector(response)
     results = sel.css('div.data-format-supply').extract()
     for index, result in enumerate(results):
         if(index == 1):
             print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **sel.css('div.AA + span:last-child::text').extract()**

The character + tells a spider to choose the span element in the brother element of a div whose class attribute has 'AA', i.e. the brother element = the second div who also has 'AA' in its class attribute.

span:last-child tells a spider to choose the last span element among span elements (under the second div, of course.) You may also write it this way: span:nth-child(2), which means to choose the second span element, obviously.